# How do I replace this undercabinet light strip?

Tags: lighting, cabinets

These under cabinet lights were here when we bought the house. Recently one stopped working & I can’t for the life of me figure out if we can replace the LED strip on it or if the entire unit needs to be replaced. I can’t seem to find a way to remove the plastic cover, covering the lights. In the first picture I can remove the covering to see the wires, but still can’t get the plastic covering the lights off. Has anyone seen this fixture or able to offer advice?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the cover off the wiring compartment, you can probably find some sort of manufacturer label that tells you a name and model number. Even if this model is no longer made, I'm sure there's info about it on the internet, you can look it up.

However, I suspect that it is *highly* unlikely that you'll be able to replace an individual LED in a strip of otherwise good ones.

It's *possible* that you'd be able to replace just the LED strip - contact the manufacturer to see if they sell them.

If you can't find that, you'd need to look at the specs for this fixture to determine how much of it you'll need to replace. If you can find the specs, you may be able to find an LED strip that's compatible and replace just the LED strip.

Odds are, though, that you won't find something precisely compatible. In that case, you could probably buy some LED light tape complete with a driver & power supply, then completely gut the fixture of the existing pieces and replace them with the new part you've purchased. You're likely going to have to go that route, because the power supply must supply the correct DC voltage to the driver and the driver has to be compatible with the wiring in the strip and with the particular LEDs that are on it.

The advantage to the gut/replace, is that you can upgrade to change the color temp of the lights and even go with dimmable ones if you desire. You might go all the way to installing smart ones that could integrate with a current/future home automation setup.